# Angular 2 css styles leaking out of component

Tags: css, angular, components

[Plunker with the problem I'm having.](https://plnkr.co/edit/UeVnD9zaQTlFHd83fwT4?p=preview) "If you comment out the styles in the ThirdComponent you can see it affect the parent and sibling components' styles." – adriancarriger (Thank you Adrian)

In my component I'm using...

```
styles: ['
    @import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    @import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css";
']
```

but it seems to ruin the style of any component that call this one. I only need the style in this one component. I thought Angular 2 components were totally independent, can't figure out why this one changes my whole web app.

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import datetimepicker from 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker';
import moment from 'moment';


@Component({
    selector: 'date-time-picker',
    styleUrls: ['../../../css/datetimepicker.css'],
    template:` 
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" 
                        a2e-datetimepicker
                        [date]="date"
                        [options]="a2eOptions"
                        (onChange)="dateChange($event)"
                        (onClick)="dateClick()"
                        />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
    `
})
export class DateTimePicker implements OnInit {

  date: moment.Moment;
  a2eOptions: any;

  dateChange(date) {
    this.date = date;
  }

  dateClick() {
    console.log('click click!')
  }

  getTime() {
    alert('Selected time is:' + this.date);
  };

  addTime(val, selector) {
    this.date = moment(this.date.add(val, selector));
  };

  clearTime() {
    this.date = null;
  };

  constructor(){
        this.date = moment();
        this.a2eOptions = {
            format: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a',
            //sideBySide: true,
            stepping: 5
        };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(datetimepicker);
  }

}
```

datetimepicker.css

```
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css";
```

Same results if I do it this way:

```
template:` 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
```

Using systemJS

Comment: Can you post your component as well ?

Comment: Your component encapsulation should be Emulated or Native

Comment: There's the component at the moment.

Comment: No way this is bleeding out , are you sure you haven't imported this styles anywhere else ? Like in your app or index.html or somewhere else ?

Comment: Yup, I am toggling the component with a button. When I enable the component, parts of my website font go white, drop down menu font goes white, some bolds get too boldy, input fields go white, so I can't see any of those fonts. Then when I disable the component, it all goes back to normal.

Comment: It looks the same way that it would look if I dropped the css links into index.html.

Comment: Hang on , could replace @import with styleUrl, that might be the issue !

Comment: styleUrls: ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' , 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'],

Comment: doing that doesn't trigger the import for some reason. I think styleUrls is only for local files or something.

Comment: You're right dude.interesting !

Comment: Are your using Systemjs or Webpack ?

Comment: I'm sure if you download the css and put them inside datePicker.css , it would work , but I don't knwo why styleUrls is not working , maybe it's a bug that should be raised

Comment: Doesn't apply correctly when I do that....

Comment: Here's a minimal [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/UeVnD9zaQTlFHd83fwT4?p=preview).. if you comment out the styles in the `ThirdComponent` you can see it affect the parent and sibling components' styles.

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what's going on. Why's it doing this? and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 4):

View encapsulation in regards of component styles works by **extending your existing selectors** with a custom attribute added by angular.

> *Example:*
>
> The host element becomes `<my-thrid-component _nghost-dra-1>`.
>   All its children become e.g. `<h3 _ngcontent-dra-1>`.
>
> Angular now takes your css selectors and extends them:
>
> `h3 { ... }` becomes `h3[_ngcontent-dra-1] { ... }`, so your styles only apply to elements in the component itself.

Now back to the *extending your existing selectors* part.
When you `@import` an external file, its content is not fetched - the file will be loaded as an external resource and therefore angular can not modify it.

Taking a look at the generated `style` tag, reveals, what's actually happening:

```
<style>
  @import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
  @import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css";

  h1[_ngcontent-dra-1],
  h2[_ngcontent-dra-1],
  h3[_ngcontent-dra-1] {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

*Conclusion:* There is no such thing as *nested imports*, therefore imported styles **are applied globally**. If your really want to include the styles only for a specific component, you need to have them locally available, so angular can read its content and extend the selectors.